# My question to ask is

Tags: word-choice

What would be a better part of a sentence besides "is because"? I am writing and my teacher has said that "is because" is not allowed in our persuasive piece. What would be better in this case than "is because"?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because a persuasive piece has to persuade the reader into agreeing or believing what you're writing and might involve something more than telling the reader "this is because of that".  You could probably ask your teacher for more clarification.

Comment: You need to provide us an example of the usage you're discussing.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "is because" is often a warning that you are writing in an over-complicated, long winded way. The solution is not to replace it with a different phrase; rather, you should consider rewriting the whole thing. "The reason you are asking the question is because you want to know the answer" would in most circumstances be much better if it were rephrased simply as "You are asking the question because you want to know the answer."

"Is because" is really a speech pattern, not a written language pattern. If you're speaking, "The reason you are asking the question ... is .. because ..." gives you time to think of an answer. When you are writing, it is better to have worked out what you want to say before writing it down.